# Javascript access denied - can't access opener after parent is no longer used in an iframe

Tags: javascript, popup, window.opener

This is not related to the domain like many other similar posts with the same error message.

Here is my set up:

```
<iframe src='somepage' />
```

user can open a window popup from within somepage and window.open is used. Assume my popup remain open and a new source page 'secondPage' is swapped into the same iframe. My popup can still its 'opener' but whenever i try to access the opener, it will throw an access denied scripting error.

so my question is, how can i either access it or check to see if it closed so i dont try to access it?  i tried to check if window.opener.closed and apparently is returning me a false.....

Comment: The word "I" is capitalised in English, as are the starts of sentences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your opener will have a property called `closed` which you can check to see if it's has been closed (or navigated away). If it's closed, checking any other property on the `opener` will throw an error because the window object has been destroyed.

I just noticed that you knew about the `closed` property. I've used this before and I never had problems.

What browser are you using? Post the code you're running. If all fails, use a `try catch` to detect that an error occurred while accessing the opener.

**IE IFRAME BUG**
What you've described is listed as bug in a comment on
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533574(v=VS.85).aspx

Comment: thanks... try catch is a good work around ... never thought of that! by the way, i was using ie9 and somehow the opener is really not closed even though explicity says frame[0].src = null. but yea..try catch seems to be a really good indication of a closed parent. thanks again!